# Disabling mouse support on ideavim

Tags: vim, pycharm, ideavim

Is there a way to disable mouse support in file edition on ideavim? It is really annoying that it enters into `visual mode` each time I click.

It isn't possible to have the same behavior as vim without mouse in terminal, but can I have it on pycharm's ideavim?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not possible to disable mouse support in Vim emulation. Note however that IdeaVim switches to Visual selection mode only when you're selecting text with the mouse. Simple clicks shouldn't make IdeaVim enter visual selection mode.

Comment: Yes it only activate when selecting, but it is really sensitive. It activates too many times when i don't want. Maybe this is specific to some of my configurations. Anyway, you answered my question.

Answer (score 6):

I also hate when the editor suddently goes into visual mode when I accidentally drag with the mouse. I ended up modifying the ideavim source and compiled my own version. I got the idea from another answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/24256022/598781

I just return immediately in the EditorMouseHandler.mouseDragged method. i.e. changed line 1772 in the file `ideavim/src/com/maddyhome/idea/vim/group/MotionGroup.java` to:

```java
if (true || !VimPlugin.isEnabled()) return;
```

This change could have some consequences, but I don't use mouse select anyway.

Comment: Wouldn't it be possible to share your compiled version as a commit to its source in github?

Answer (score 2):

You should try `:set selectmode=mouse,ideaselection`. It is a workaround but that worked for me.
https://github.com/JetBrains/ideavim/blob/master/doc/set-commands.md